# How to keep part of the pattern in the match?

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
<sk n=1 x=1>test<ent n=1 x=1>AAAAAAA</ent></sk><sk n=1>test2<ent>BBBBBB</ent></sk>
```

With this pattern:

```
<sk(?:.*?)>(?:.*?)<(.*?)<\/sk>
```

I get these 2 groups:

```
1: ent n=1 x=1>AAAAAAA</ent>
2: ent>BBBBBB</ent>
```

How can I get the results include the "<", like this:

```
1: <ent n=1 x=1>AAAAAAA</ent>
2: <ent>BBBBBB</ent>
```

Is there anything I can add in the pattern to get that? Otherwise I have to add it "manually" but I don't think that is the right approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the `<` in the group:

```
<sk(?:.*?)>(?:.*?)(<.*?)<\/sk>
```

[**Demonstration**](http://rubular.com/r/xRI5KEyWc7)